# Не работает обработчик ошибок

Tags: node.js, исключения, express, middleware, exception-handler

В приложении на `express.js` не работает middleware для обработки ошибок.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "platform",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "node src/index.js",
    "start:prod": "node src/index.js",
    "migrate": "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sequelize": "^6.12.0-beta.1",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/api/user/registration', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
})

//error handler
app.use((err, req, res) => {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Custom error' });
});


(async function start() {
    try {
        app.listen(3010, () => console.log(`Server listen: 3010`))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

При попытке отправить POST-запрос на `localhost:3010/api/user/registration`, в консоль логируется ошибка:

```
Error
    at \platform\src\index.js:15:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\platform\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (\platform\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (\platform\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\platform\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (\platform\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)       
    at next (\platform\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at \platform\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (\platform\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[В документации](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/error-handling.html#:%7E:text=%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%2C%20%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%3A) на чистом английском написано чтобы обработчика ошибок должно быть **4** аргумента. Иначе как экспресс должен его отличить от обычной мидлвари?

Comment: Больше объяснений ошибки богу ошибок! =)

Comment: @nörbörnën о, оказывается и на русском есть

Comment: Это действительно помогло, счастья вам и вашей семье!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что именно вы посылаете запросом POST, в каком формате и в какой кодировке

```
app.use(express.json());
```

у JSON очень привередливый синтаксис. В случае первого же символа, не вписывающегося в синтаксис JSON, прога будет выдавать исключения.